# The CLLocationManagerDelegate didUpdateLocations callback comes back on the main thread when startUpdatingLocation is called from a background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cllocationmanager

I am attempting to request the users location from a background thread and, once receieved, handle the callback (`didUpdateLocations`) from this background thread. The background thread is started using `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: toTarget: withObject:]`

According to the Apple documentation for CLLocationManagerDelegate:

> The methods of your delegate object are called from the thread in which you started the corresponding location services. That thread must itself have an active run loop, like the one found in your application’s main thread.

I have checked that the request is definitely on a background thread and the callback is definitely on the main thread using `[NSThread currentThread]`.

So this background thread where I call `startUpdatingLocations` either doesn't have an active run loop or this is not the thread in which I started the "location service".

My question is: why is the callback coming back on the main thread when the request is clearly from a background thread?

**UPDATE:** Just a thought: perhaps the background thread is destroyed before getting the callback, killing the run loop so the callback executes on the main thread?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate) may have been inaccurate. It has been updated now to say:

> Core Location calls the methods of your delegate object on the runloop **from the thread on which you initialized CLLocationManager**.

So it seems it is based on the thread where you created the location manager and **not** the thread where you call `startUpdatingLocations`.